# How can I serve a JSON object containing JSX over HTTP (without having to sacrifice DX to serialize it manually)

Tags: http, next.js, serialization, jsx, esbuild

I am using Next.js to make a web app containing frontend web development lessons. The first few lessons should be free, but the others should be behind a paywall. Since the lesson content is very interactive, I am storing it as JSX. It would not be feasible for me to store it any other way without significantly slowing down development.

So to recap:

Because some of these lessons are behind a paywall, I need to store and serve the content on the server, which means I need to figure out a way to serialize the JSX **while still storing JSX** (in other words, I don't want to represent the JSX with objects, because that would be a poor DX).

I've looked at how [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/) serves their lesson contents (which are also very interactive), and it seems that they are compiling and bundling the lesson contents (I don't know if they store it as JSX like myself), and then they serve the compiled js as a string:

[image]

So, I tried to do the same. In my attempts, I have used [ESBuild](https://esbuild.github.io/)'s API because it is astonishingly fast, allowing me to potentially bundle the lesson contents *on request*

At first I tried bundling some test code I wrote specifically for this purpose with the ESBuild CLI. Once I got that to work, I tried to do it programatically using ESBuild's API. This time I was trying to bundle the actual lesson contents. Unfortunately, for some reason, trying to bundle any component that was using the `useRouter()` hook threw 3 errors about how I was trying to import node-specific modules in my bundled code (which is weird because you'd think the `useRouter()` hook would run on the client at some point during runtime)

So when that didn't work, I made a quick project where I just made 1 component with a simple animation using `framer-motion`. I bundled it using the API with the following config:

```js
const esbuild = require("esbuild");
const { nodeExternalsPlugin } = require("esbuild-node-externals");
esbuild
  .build({
    entryPoints: ["./src/Square.tsx"],
    outfile: "dist/Square.js",
    bundle: true,
    minify: true,
    platform: "browser",
    format: "iife",
    globalName: "Square",
    plugins: [nodeExternalsPlugin()],
  })
  .catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

This resulted in the following code:

```js
var Square=(()=>{var d=Object.create;var e=Object.defineProperty;var p=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor;var b=Object.getOwnPropertyNames;var c=Object.getPrototypeOf,f=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;var u=(t=>typeof require<"u"?require:typeof Proxy<"u"?new Proxy(t,{get:(a,o)=>(typeof require<"u"?require:a)[o]}):t)(function(t){if(typeof require<"u")return require.apply(this,arguments);throw Error('Dynamic require of "'+t+'" is not supported')});var x=(t,a)=>{for(var o in a)e(t,o,{get:a[o],enumerable:!0})},m=(t,a,o,s)=>{if(a&&typeof a=="object"||typeof a=="function")for(let r of b(a))!f.call(t,r)&&r!==o&&e(t,r,{get:()=>a[r],enumerable:!(s=p(a,r))||s.enumerable});return t};var w=(t,a,o)=>(o=t!=null?d(c(t)):{},m(a||!t||!t.__esModule?e(o,"default",{value:t,enumerable:!0}):o,t)),y=t=>m(e({},"__esModule",{value:!0}),t);var g={};x(g,{default:()=>l});var i=u("framer-motion"),n=w(u("react"),1);function l(){let t=(0,i.useAnimationControls)();return(0,n.useEffect)(()=>{(async()=>{await t.start({scale:2,rotate:360,left:"50%",top:"50%"}),t.set({rotate:0}),await t.start({rotate:[0,-45,540],borderRadius:["6px","50%"],filter:["blur(0px)","blur(1px)","blur(0px)"],transition:{duration:1.25,filter:{times:[.6,.85,1]},borderRadius:{times:[.5,.95],duration:1.25},rotate:{times:[0,.5,1],duration:1.25}}})})()},[]),n.default.createElement(i.motion.button,{animate:t,className:"w-12 aspect-square bg-neutral-300 rounded-md absolute",transition:{delay:1,duration:2,type:"spring"}})}return y(g);})();
```

However, when ran, I get:

[image]

I also looked at [react-serialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-serialize) but during my brief attempt it didn't seem to work, the `serialize` function just returned undefined. (To be honest I'm actively avoiding that library anyway, but if it works, I'll use it)

Comment: ESbuild cannot convert external "static" commonjs require statements to static esm imports, not even for the side effect free node platform built in modules. More about this issue can be found [here](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1921).

Comment: @FabioNettis I've seen that particular issue on the hub, but it doesn't seem like a solution was ever reached. Is it possible to work around this issue? Do II have to do something different? How should I proceed?